# Creating an irregularly shaped Gdk Window

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, gtk, cairo

Gtk3 has the `shape_combine_region` method which takes a `cairo.Region` object ([see docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Windows.html)) which allows making the window a non rectangular shape. This would be straightforward by turning my `cairo.ImageSurface` (created from a png) into a region with `Gdk.cairo_region_create_from_surface`, however pycairo does not support the `cairo.Region` in Python 2.

What would be the most elegant work around to accomplish this?

Comment: @Isma I'm not trying to hide a window, but changing it into an irregular shape. Modifying question to make that clearer

Comment: I would say upgrade to python3 (you should strongly consider this if this is a new project, python2 will reach EOL by 2020) or use C for gtk3 or try gtk2, the method you mentioned is available and accepts GdkRegion instead of Cairo's Region.

Comment: GTK+2 included an [example](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/gtk-2-24/examples/wheelbarrow/wheelbarrow.c) (IMO more a proof of concept) of non-rectangular window handling.