# Create custom shaped Cairo::Region

Tags: rust, cairo, gtk-rs

Looking through the documentation of [cairo::Region](https://gtk-rs.org/docs/cairo/struct.Region.html) I can't find any functions allowing me to create not rectangle shaped regions. Did I miss something or is this simply not possible?

Comment: "Regions are a simple graphical data type representing an area of integer-aligned rectangles. They are often used on raster surfaces to track areas of interest, such as change or clip areas.", https://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Regions.html

Comment: In what word do you expect this to be something else than rectangle ? cairo crate is a binding read the original doc

Comment: I see only rectangles makes sense. I got the idea from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48029084/creating-an-irregularly-shaped-gdk-window in which it sounded like you could get any shaped regions.